# Running a SQL Query using BCP

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I just started learning to use SQL Server's BCP and I'm using it to query a SQL Server DB and create a .csv file.  I can create the file with no problem using this command:

bcp "SELECT 'ID' FROM [database].[dbo].[table]" queryout C:\DeskTop\test.csv -c -t, -T -S

However, I need to run a more advance query and I'm have problems.  It seems the query is getting parsed and the parts are trying to be executed.  I'm getting errors say FROM command not found.  Here's the query I'm trying to run in the BCP command:

```
SELECT REPLICATE(0, 10-LEN(t.[CustId])) + CAST(t.[CustId] as       
                                                 nvarchar) as CustId
   ,(CASE WHEN t.[DisclId] = 'ECONSENT' THEN 'eConsent'
          WHEN t.[DisclId] = 'OLACC' THEN 'OLACC' END) as DisclId
   ,CONVERT(DATE,t.[AgreeDateTime],23) AS AgreeDateTime
  ,t.[Vers]
  ,'0' as ACNT_ID
  ,'Accepted' as Status_Desc
  ,'0001-01-01' as Last_Delay_Date
  ,'0' as Delay_Count
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustId, DisclId 
      ORDER BY AgreeDateTime DESC) AS RowNumber 
FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE]) AS t
WHERE t.RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY CustId
```

What is the correct syntax to run this query using the BCP command?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How does your final `BCP` query looks like. Hope you have used single quotation marks around anything embedded in the query.

Comment: That is one thing I didn't do.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: I found my problem.  I had the query wrapped in quotation marks which I needed but by typing it in and testing it piece by piece (meaning I added items to the select statement one at a time and then ran the BCP command) I was able to run it with no problem.  Before I was copying and pasting large parts in the query.

Answer (score 1):

bcp likes "inline queries" best, where the query can be concatenated into a single line for the cmd prompt.  I have several cases where my SQL Statement is too large for that deal.  You might be able to get away with it, but if not, create a view.

Use the view to output.  That's what I did.

To that end, here's how I output a view:

```
bcp.exe <database>.dbo.<VIEW NAME> out "Drive:\Folder Path\file.csv" -T -S localhost -c -t"|" -C65001
```

however, to answer your immediate question, replace the view name in the above example with your query, surrounded by double quotes.

This will give you a UTF-8 enabled pipe-delimited CSV.